# Use Imgur API with Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, imgur

I am developing a web app with angular and I'm having trouble using Imgur API. My goal is to have a form where a user selects its photo and then I upload it to imgur and I store the link where the image was stored.

However, I have two problems:
what is the best way to "store" the image? 
Currently I'm using the "change" property and I'm storing it with this:

```
  this.file = event.srcElement.files
```

Is this the right way?

Then I'm having trouble sending the image to the API.

```
var headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID {{id-here}}'};
this.http.post(url, payload, headers)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        response.json() as string;
                    })
                    .catch(this.handleError);
```

The server responds with 401 - unauthorized.
I'm probably loading the client ID the wrong way, just don't know how I'm supposed to do it.

The same with the payload, how should I declare it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you verified if the Authorization header is really being sent? If not, go to the developers panel (ctrl + shift + i), switch to the 'Network' tab and  do the call. Look in the 'Headers' tab, find your request and inspect the 'Request headers' of the api call, it should contain the 'Authorization' header. If it is not there, further code analysis needs to be done.

Comment: If you haven't yet reached the api documentation here is it. https://apidocs.imgur.com/ As I can see, if you have the client id you can already do api calls to public read-only resources.

Comment: Yeah, the authorization wasn't being sent. Already fixed it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to pcarrara I was able to sort what was wrong.

Need to declare the headers like this:

`var headers = new Headers({'authorization': 'Client-ID clientid'});`

Then send it like this:

```
this.http.post(imgurl, photo, {headers: headers})
```

I read the photo using

```
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" #fileInput>

    @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef;
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    this.file = inputEl.files.item(0);
```

Just posting the solution here in case someone has the same problem. :)