# How do I upload images to images to imgur in an angular application?

Tags: angular, image-uploading, imgur

I currently am developing front-end of a blogging website in which a user is allowed to add feature image for the blog and the feature image is stored in cloud storage. I'm trying to use **Imgur** as the cloud storage for the feature images here.

I've never used cloud storage to store images of my website. So what is the suggested way to upload images in **Imgur** using **Angular**.

Also, I've read the docs and created a application in **Imgur** so I've got the client-id and client-secret for the application. I've authenticated my application in **POSTMAN** but I'm not understanding how to authenticate and authorise my application to access **Imgur** inside **Angular**.

Comment: if you check your console then you might be found its a cross origin issue that error you getting

Comment: No I've handled the cross origin issue already. The status error is 400 when I try to access the upload image route.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Imgur API it has a `REST API` which you can communicate with. In other words you can use HTTP request to upload the image from your angular application. In order to Imgur API to accept data from your application you need to specify the client-Id in the `HTTP` request headers.

Sample implementation of that API call will look something like this:

```
let headers = new Headers({'authorization': 'Client-ID clientid'});
this.http.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/upload', photo, {headers: headers})
```

> Please find the Imgur Official API doumentation [here](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#de179b6a-3eda-4406-a8d7-1fb06c17cb9c)
>
> You can find another reference on how to upload image using Imgur API
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869434/use-imgur-api-with-angular4)

Comment: The image itself should be passed on as form-data or the image file itself? Because right now I'm trying to send image as form-data and I still get 400 error.

Comment: Usually 400 means that API definition and your request definition doesnt match. Yes it clearly said that it is passed as form data.. Getting this type of specific error means that you are on correct track.  Also it allows passing the image as base64 image type too. Appreciate marking this as a correct answer and giving an upvote to this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also, adding just client-id in the header is for uploading the image anonymously. If I want to upload image to a specific account I might have to add the access token in the header instead of client-id. So how do I do that?

Comment: Yes you can specify the access tokens and all too Refer to [this](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#authorization-and-oauth) section on their documentation it is all defined. In case of an acquiring an access token you need to initiate another request before the uploading and use it in the uploading request. Would you mind giving an upvote to the answer too? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was getting 400 error while trying to access the Imgur API in angular application was I was trying to access **https://api.imgur.com/3/upload** url.
This URL for some reason is working just in POSTMAN. For accessing the Imgur API in your application use this url: **https://api.imgur.com/3/image**